# How to get UK County name if we have the lat long

Tags: geolocation, html5-video, geocoding, openlayers-3

1. User clicks on the 'locate me' button
2. The lat long is populated using HTML5 navigator.geolocation feature
3. I need to retrieve the county name now
4. I would also like to avoid Google Maps Geocode API as there are usage limits & I'm already using it for some other purpose

Comment: 1. Create a little database with county names and lat lng limits. 2. Check each user entry with database.

Comment: Time to give a feedback?

Comment: In the end, I didn't need this actually. Hence the delay :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Reverse Geocoding service like [OSM](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Reverse_Geocoding) or [Photon](http://photon.komoot.de) - [live demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jonataswalker/r88e75dz/).